# Help with inverse Laplace of a circuit solution in time domain

Tags: laplace-transform

A part of a circuit has the transfer function in s domain as:

H(s) = R / (s×R×C + 1)

V(s) = I(s) × H(s)

and the input is a pulse current with an area: 1, pulse duration: a and amplitude 1/a. And its Laplace transform is given as:

(1 - exp(a×s)) / (a×s)

Now for the voltage:

V(s) = [(1 - exp(a×s)) / (a×s)] × [R / (s×R×C + 1)]

Now the above equation requires to take the inverse Laplace transform and it is complicated to my rusty math. What would voltage V(t) be obtained in time domain? I don't need the derivation, the result is fine. A solution through tool or calculator would be also very fine. It needs to show V(t) including R, C, a parameters.

Comment: **1** have you tried partial fraction expansion of the expression in s domain? **2** you could apply the linearity property. Find inverse transform of \$\frac{1}{s(RCs+1)}\$ and \$\frac{e^{-as}}{s(RCs+1)}\$ separately and then join the results using subtraction. The inverse transform of the second expression can be further simplified using time shift property.

Answer (score 0):

Real time result with [microcap v12](https://spectrum-soft.com)

E1 is component Laplace_Function  LF VofV, R1 is irrelevant but needed (any value).

[image]

V1 is a pulse generator.

[image]

Add the 4 Text ".define ..." and Text labels needed.

When schematic done, click on ".define ...", change value with "up" or "down" arrows.

[image]